# Upload speed test

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I'm developing an app with Laravel and VueJs, which should make upload speed tests.
To do this, I already had in my Vue component a script recording a few minutes of webCam, and upload it to the server via a Form included in axios post request. 
To calculate the transfer speed, in my php Controller, I get the current timestamp, also timestamp of sending the request and the content length of my http request. 
The speed should be speed = length / time 
But unfortunately, the results are so far from the real speed when i did tests in some websites testSpeed because of the request time that is not correct.
In Chrome inspection through the network, i see several times, as "request sent", "waiting ttfb", "content download" and more... I think that the time corresponding to the request time sent is the "request sent", but i have not idea how to got it in my php script.

here are screenshots of my script and the result:

```
public function analyse(Request $request)
{
    $currentTimestamp = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $requestSentAt = round($request->server->get('REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT') * 1000);
    $deliveryTime = ($currentTimestamp - $requestSentAt) / 1000;
    $contentLength = $request->server->get('CONTENT_LENGTH') / 1000000;
    $speed = $contentLength / $deliveryTime;

    dd($speed." Mo/S");


}
```

[Chrome debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRagn.png)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGYpK.png)

Do you think that my logic doing this calculus is right ? 
Do you have an idea or suggestion ?

I'm really blocked in this step. 
I really appreciate your help in advance.
Thank you very much and have a good day .

Comment: Please post the code itself in the question, not an image of the code - it's really hard to debug images :|

Comment: ok, let's go :)

Comment: Show us the data in a couple of examples.